# google colab with R no rendering plotly figures

Tags: r, plotly, google-colaboratory

Im trying to use the plotly library on google colab using R, i created a new colaboratory notebook with R kernel , tried this simple code from plotly's documentation and result is white cell (seems size of histogram but its not rendering) anyone did experience this issue?

```
p <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50), type = "histogram")

p
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: there is no solution until google fix it